The phantoms in my devices. Malware? Rat?
I have multiple phones and PCs that do their own thing. They are connected on some phantom (network/Bluetooth?) connection, and I am not sure how, where it originates, or how to stop it.
I’m going to just refer to issues that happened to a win 11 laptop that I have not connected to any Wi-Fi or Bluetooth, ever. I had it sitting around for two weeks afraid to connect it so it wouldn’t end up like my other devices. The first thing I did when I got it was disable the BT and Wi-Fi. Anytime I had it turned on, I did not have my wifi connected and had all my devices turned off, just in case.
When I turned it on, I got the blue Lock Screen you get when you have a phone, etc connected. When I was double checking the firewall rules, I noticed it said it was connected via private network on the firewall status screen. Nothing in netstat. I had already uninstalled Phone Link and connected devices. Every time I go to log off of this device when the blue screen is up it tells me other people are still logged in and if I’m sure I want to log out. I use Malbytesware firewall control and I saw in event viewer that an account was reinstating deleted/blocked rules. Ones I don’t even see in the list.
I finally hardwire connected the thing right to my modem for the first time tonight and about 30 seconds went by and I got that windows defender caught Behavior:Win32/WDBlockFirewallRule.P in c:\windows\system32\svchost.exe.
I had caught that threat only once before. But it was the same threat on one of my other devices. I can’t even tell you how many times I have reformatted/reset/replaced all the things trying to get my devices back to normal, and it was just once. So odd.
The affected PCs will be running 10+ copies of svchost on some phantom account, using a LOT of data where my IP seemed to be getting flagged. All of my devices - phones, security cameras, TVs are affected too, but I am not sure if the incidents are even related (these are remote accessed somehow).  I’ve been wracking my brain about this for over a year. The one thing they ALL have in common is Bluetooth.
Any help or insight or a place to begin would be appreciated!

There’s nothing we can do to help, but I’d advise you to look for common factors- e.g. one device you haven’t cleaned and reset. It might also be a good idea to check-in with someone you trust to make sure everything you’re experiencing is real.
